# Is there a way to change the value of the number to text in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, string, integer

I am trying to change the numbers to a 'p' or 'f' based on the score.

Not sure how to add images so here is a link

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dKn9mkJa9brZXq2tHz8_ULkgreWsBkTI/view?usp=sharing

I have already stripped the % sign from the string but i now need to change the number based on the score. >=70 to a 'p', 69 and lower to a 'f'

```
Sub PassOrFail()


Dim myValue As String

myValue = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("testScore").Value

myValue = Replace(myValue, "%", "")



MsgBox myValue


End Sub
```

Expecting it to show Skim: p, MP: f

Comment: I think you should add some data example of how those % are stored in cells. It will be helpful.

Comment: If your `myValue` is always under the same format, it would be a matter of splitting at `;`, and make case scenario on the values. I`ll try to make an example, unless someone else is faster.

Comment: Presuming that your format for the range that holds the values is in percentage format, you could use something like: `If myValue >= 0.7 Then`. If it greater, it's a pass otherwise, it's a fail

Answer (score 0):

is this what u need ?

```
if cInt(myValue) >=70 then
  myValue="p"
elseif cInt(myValue><69 then
   myValue="f"
end if
```

thanks

Comment: That wouldn't work, because there are 2 different values in `myValue`.

Comment: so myValue will be like ";Skim:100%;MP:17%" ?

Comment: If you think this could solve the problem, you should add some explanation to the code such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

Try this code below:

```
Sub PassOrFail()

Dim myValue As String
myValue = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("testScore").Value

'String manipulation starts here
'1. Get the pattern position
Dim skim_pos As Integer, mp_pos As Integer
skim_pos = InStr(myValue, "Skim: ")
mp_pos = InStr(myValue, ";MP: ")

'2. Get the skim score
Dim skim As String
skim = Replace(Mid(myValue, skim_pos + 6, mp_pos - (skim_pos + 6)), "%", "")

'3. Get the MP
Dim mp As String
mp = Replace(Mid(myValue, mp_pos + 5, Len(myValue) - (my_pos + 5)), "%", "")

If CInt(skim) >= 70 Then
    skim = "p"
Else
    skim = "f"
End If

If CInt(mp) >= 70 Then
    mp = "p"
Else
    mp = "f"
End If

MsgBox "Skim: " & skim & ", MP: " & mp


End Sub
```

Comment: Interesting aproach, but both yours and mine relies heavily on strings not changing at all.

Answer (score 0):

Although not the most elegant solution, it works based on given details:

```
Sub PassOrFail()

Dim myValue As String, strResult As String
Dim arrResults

myValue = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("testScore").Value

'Split the value
arrResults = Split(Replace(myValue, "%", ""), ";") 'This would create a 3 column array, due to the initial ";"

    'Skim
    If Replace(arrResults(1), "Skim: ", "") >= 70 Then
        strResult = "Skim: p"
    Else
        strResult = "Skim: f"
    End If

    'MP
    If Replace(arrResults(2), "MP: ", "") >= 70 Then
        strResult = strResult + ", MP: p"
    Else
        strResult = strResult + ", MP: f"
    End If

    'Result
    MsgBox strResult

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution not based on "Skim" or "MP" but on the %-sign:

```
Sub tst()
Dim mystring As String, y As Variant, i As Long
    mystring = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("testScore")
    y = Split(mystring, " ")
        For i = 1 To UBound(y)
            If InStr(y(i), "%") > 0 Then
                If Val(Split(Split(y(i), " ")(0), "%")(0)) < 70 Then
                    mystring = Replace(mystring, Split(Split(y(i), " ")(0), "%")(0) & "%", "f")
                Else
                    mystring = Replace(mystring, Split(Split(y(i), " ")(0), "%")(0) & "%", "p")
                End If
            End If
        Next i
MsgBox mystring
End Sub
```

Comment: For what is worth, it works, and very compact... though not returning the result quite in the requested format... `;Skim: p;MP: f` . However, for readability sake... i`d prefer something else.

Comment: I missed the desired outcome at the bottom, a split on "Skim:" and "MP:" is IMO the best option

Comment: Oh btw, it should be only `)(0)) < 70 Then` instead of `)(0)) <= 70 Then`, otherwise 70 is also considered as fail.